# TableSorter with Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, tablesorter

Im using the `Jquery Tablesorter` plugin and `Drag and Drop` plugin together all works fine but when I try to use the serialize function of the `tableDnD` it says: `empty string getElementById`

I use it Like this( js is placed under the table):

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#manage").tableDnD({onDrop: function(table, row) {alert($.tableDnD.serialize());}});
                });
                function UpdateOrder () {
                    alert("Test Button Clicked!");
                    var pneworder = document.getElementById("manage").tableDnD.serialize();            
                    alert(pneworder);
                    $.post("inc/testpost.php", { "neworder": pneworder } );
                }
            </script>
```

Button Code:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="UpdateOrder()" name="Test" value = "Test"></button>
```

With the `onDrop` event it works fine it shows the alert with the serialized info, but with the button click it just gives me error in js console and I just get first alert "Test Button Clicked!".

Any help would be great, since Im new to Javascript.

EDIT:
I just tried to getElementsByTag("table") there it tells me that table with "manage" as id exists but when I try to use it like that `elements[0].tableDnD.serialize()` it still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

If this table has multiple TBODYs. The functionality isn’t quite working properly. You can only drag the rows inside each TBODY, you can’t drag them outside it. Now this might or might not be what you want, but unfortunately if you then drop a row outside its TBODY you get a Javascript error because inserting after a sibling doesn’t work.

Comment: I just have one THead, one TBody and one TFoot so I guess this isn't causing the error I just get the error when I look into console(ctrl+shift+j) otherwise it just doesn't even open an alert.